# How to hide HTML and Javascript codes from Inspect Element and View source options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, encryption

I've made my web application and did hardwork to make this almost lost 180 days to make this. All my application is made into JAvascript. But i could see, many smart persons still can steal my codes. Can you please help me? How to encrypt in such a way that my code will never show into Inspect element and View Source? Is there any Algorithm?

Here is my code When i see into inspect Element and View Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="app">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 

        <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, admin dashboard, admin, flat, flat ui, ui kit, off screen nav" /> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jplayer.flat.css" type="text/css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.v1.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/load_bar.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/load_bar.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.v1.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/app.plugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/music_list.js">                                                               
        </script>

--------
--------
--------


    <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script> <script src="js/ie/respond.min.js"></script> <script src="js/ie/excanvas.js"></script> <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="some-content-related-div" id="inner-content-div"> 
    <section class="vbox">
```

***PLEASE HELP, How to Encrypt it?***

HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!

Comment: Do you read my Actual Questions?, If not ..read it again..

Comment: Frankly you can't, only thing you can do is minify.
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679177/how-can-i-obfuscate-or-make-unreadable-my-javascript-files#answer-8679192) you will get in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Javascript code is executed in the browser, i.e. on the client side, which means it must be available not-encrypted on the client side.

The "best" you can do is probably to minify it, which will make it harder to understand it -- and a bit of [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code)  might do too -- even if someone really motivated will still be able to read it.

See for instance the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) , which can both minify and obfuscate JS code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You can't.

The only thing you can do is to uglify everything so it's not easy to read anymore, but anything that is sent to the browser is also theoretically visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible but you can minify it using many compressors which are available online.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do this. You can disable the inspect element functionality by adding the code snippet below :-

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){
       return false;
    }
});
```